# Adding on click event to Galleria link using JSON

Tags: jquery, json, hyperlink, onclick, galleria

I have set up my first Galleria gallery using JSON.

Would it be possible to add another function to the on click event for each of the four links I have for my four images?

Is there a way to add another variable to the JSON data or assign a class to each individual image?

The analytics my CMS uses has to be called via an on click function so this is essential on my site.

Many thanks,
H

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to add another
>   function to the on click event for
>   each of the four links I have for my
>   four images?

Yes, you can bind any amount of handlers to the same event. Just do (as usual):

```
$("selector").click(function(){
   //your code here
});
```

> Is there a way to add another variable
>   to the JSON data or assign a class to
>   each individual image?

I don't know how Galleria's json structure, but if you have the selector, you can add a class (as usual) as:

```
$("image_selector").addClass("className");
```

Sorry if some things seemed obvious to you.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can add more variables to Galleria's JSON structure. I have successfully added a property called "video" for every object to stream M-JPG when the picture loads.